# Django aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented

Tags: django

Не получается составить запрос.

Задача - выбрать все одинаковые услуги, и посчитать их среднюю минимальную и среднюю максимальную цену.

Не могу сообразить как сделать:

```
pricelist = PriceList.objects.distinct('service')
```

Таким образом можно сделать group_by по названию услуги.

```
pricelist = PriceList.objects.aggregate(Avg('from_price'), Avg('to_price'))
```

Таким образом можно получить все усреднённые цены.

```
pricelist = PriceList.objects.distinct('service').aggregate(Avg('from_price'), Avg('to_price'))
```

Пытался сделать так, на что получил:

> Django aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.

и только потом понял почему :)

Если я делаю `distinct('service')`, то исключаю все повторяющиеся записи, а они мне как раз таки нужны, для вычисления среднего значения, а после `aggregate` остаётся словарь с ключом и значением.

Если использовать `annotate`, то он добавляет к каждому объекту `QuerySet` результаты выражений.

Как сделать правильно ?

```
class PriceList(models.Model):
    provider = AutoOneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='Поставщик', 
        primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey('service.Service', null=True, blank=True, 
        verbose_name='Услуга')
    from_price = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', 
        verbose_name='Цена от', null=True)
    to_price = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', 
        verbose_name='Цена до', null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял, что к полю `service` нужно добавить `related_name`, например `provider_price` и делать `annotate` у модели `Service`, примерно так:

```
prices = Service.objects.annotate(avg_from_price=Avg('provider_price__from_price'), avg_to_price=Avg('provider_price__to_price'))
```